# C# - No POST body in WS SOAP 1.2 request with WSHttpBinding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am stuck with SOAP 1.2 request to ONVIF device.

My code is:

```
        var c = "http://192.168.31.12:5000/onvif/device_service";

        var wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        wsBinding.Name = "My WSHttpBinding";

        wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        CustomBinding l_CustomBinding = new CustomBinding(wsBinding);
        MessageEncodingBindingElement l_EncodingElement =
             l_CustomBinding.Elements.Find<MessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        l_EncodingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(c);

        fgdfsdfsdg.ServiceReference1.DeviceClient cl = new ServiceReference1.DeviceClient(l_CustomBinding, endpointAddress);
        fgdfsdfsdg.ServiceReference1.GetDeviceInformationRequest inValue = new fgdfsdfsdg.ServiceReference1.GetDeviceInformationRequest();
        var Q = cl.GetDeviceInformationAsync(inValue).Result;
```

What I see in Wireshark:

```
POST /onvif/device_service HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetDeviceInformation"
Host: 192.168.31.12:5000
Content-Length: 261
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

What expected by WS:

```
POST /onvif/device_service HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/GetDeviceInformation"
Host: 192.168.31.12:5000
Content-Length: 261
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Close

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetDeviceInformation xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

What should I add to my code to make C# send request body too, not only headers in HTTP POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the header

```
Expect: 100-continue
```

which coming from `HttpWebRequest`. To disable this header I had to add

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

before my code, ie my code now is

```
        var c = "http://192.168.31.12:5000/onvif/device_service";

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        wsBinding.Name = "My WSHttpBinding";

        wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

        CustomBinding l_CustomBinding = new CustomBinding(wsBinding);
        MessageEncodingBindingElement l_EncodingElement =
             l_CustomBinding.Elements.Find<MessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        l_EncodingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;
```

The solution was found here https://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx/ :

> Apparently I’m not the only one to run into this annoying problem.
>   When using the HttpWebRequest to POST form data using HTTP 1.1, it
>   ALWAYS adds the following HTTP header “Expect: 100-Continue”. Fixing
>   the problem has proved to be quite elusive.
>
> According to the HTTP 1.1 protocol, when this header is sent, the form
>   data is not sent with the initial request. Instead, this header is
>   sent to the web server which responds with 100 (Continue) if
>   implemented correctly. However, not all web servers handle this
>   correctly, including the server to which I am attempting to post data.
>   I sniffed the headers that Internet Explorer sends and noticed that it
>   does not send this header, but my code does.
>
> .......................
>
> UPDATE: Lance Olson points me to the solution in my comments section.
>   The System.Net.ServicePointManager class has a static property named
>   Expect100Continue. Setting this to false will stop the header “Expect:
>   100-Continue” from being sent.